# Generating a random winner and displaying the odds of winning - am I doing this right?

Tags: sql, math, probability

I'm running a contest on a website and I have 3215 entrants who are eligible for 5x Sony PSPs.

I believe the formula to count the odds is totalEntrants - prizes / prizes:

`(3215-5)/5 = 642` so that's an odds of 642 to 1 of winning - is that right? ( I suck at math )

And in my table which contains 3215 rows in the database I would just select a random row like so?

```
SELECT * from entries
WHERE entries.won = 0
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 1
```

Now I have one row, and I need to set the `won` column to `1` so the entrant can't win again, then run it again? This is my first time doing it so I just want confirmation on if I'm doing it correctly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's right. Five people can win, there are 3215 entrants, so the odds of winning are 3215 ÷ 5 which is 1 in 643, or 642-to-1. 1 in every 643 wins meaning there are 642 losers to every 1 winner. Note the subtle one-off difference between "x in y chance" versus "x-to-y chance".

Your selection method looks fine. You could also select them all at once by changing it to `LIMIT 5`.

Comment: Ah ok, so I'd need a second statement to update all 5 rows' `won` column to 1 and I'm good?

Comment: You've got it. Something like `UPDATE entries SET won = 1 WHERE id IN (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)` would work.

Answer (score 2):

Why not just use `LIMIT 5` to select the winners in one step?

Comment: It doesn't ensure that a person will win only once, unless you assume that a person only entered once (unlikely).

Comment: I'm controlling all the entries and preventing any duplicates

Answer (score 2):

Winning odds are **totalEntrants / prizes**

There is no need to reduce the number of prizes. e.g., if we have 2 entrants and one prize the odds are 2/1, meaning each entrant has one of two chance to win (if we'd reduce the number of prizes it's be 1/1, meaning one to one chance - sure win...)

The query seems right:

- Same entrant won't get selected twice
  (assuming you have code that updates
  the *'won'* field)
- User will be selected randomly by RANDOM generating different order each time querying

Comment: To produce the odds if I didn't reduce the number of prizes wouldn't the odds ratio be off? 2/1.0 = 2 to 1, when it's 1 to 1 and that would be if we subtracted with 2-1/1.

Comment: Assuming the meaning of odds are the chance of each entrant to win then it must be entrant/prizes. It's how prizes divides between entrants.
If there is a group of three entrants and there is only one prize then each one has 1 to 3 chance to win. It can't be 1 to 2...

Answer (score 1):

I think you can't select and update in the same query. What I would do is to use your query to select a random winner and execute an update on the register whose ID was returned to change the field "won" to have value 1. Then you just repeat the process 4 times. :)

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE won LIKE ENTRIES;

DECLARE numAwards INT DEFAULT 5;

WHILE numAwards > 0 DO

  INSERT INTO won
    (columns...)
    SELECT e.*
      FROM ENTRIES e
     WHERE e.userid NOT IN (SELECT w.userid FROM won)
  ORDER BY RAND()
     LIMIT 1;

  SET numAwards = numAwards - 1;

END WHILE;
```

You could also use:

```
   SELECT e.*
     FROM ENTRIES e
LEFT JOIN won w ON w.userid = e.userid
    WHERE w.userid IS NULL
  ORDER BY RAND()
     LIMIT 1;
```

...but there's no difference in performance - see: [NOT IN vs. NOT EXISTS vs. LEFT JOIN / IS NULL: MySQL](http://explainextended.com/2009/09/18/not-in-vs-not-exists-vs-left-join-is-null-mysql/)

**UPDATE**: Using `LIMIT 5` is not ideal because it doesn't ensure that a person will win only once, unless you assume that a person only entered once (unlikely).

Comment: I've never actually used a temporary table before, how would this method differentiate from what I have if I changed it to LIMIT 5?